# what is "wxd" in rocketcore?

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

In the rocket core bypass logic

```
 val bypass_sources = IndexedSeq(
(Bool(true), UInt(0), UInt(0)), // treat reading x0 as a bypass
(ex_reg_valid && ex_ctrl.wxd, ex_waddr, mem_reg_wdata),
(mem_reg_valid && mem_ctrl.wxd && !mem_ctrl.mem, mem_waddr, wb_reg_wdata),
(mem_reg_valid && mem_ctrl.wxd, mem_waddr, dcache_bypass_data))
```

What do **ex_ctrl.wxd** and **mem_ctrl.wxd** stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, `wxd` is set for an instruction that writes a value to a register, i.e. has a result value, so writes to the register file.  Some reasonably simple decode logic (e.g. test for R-type instruction) identifies whether each instruction is such a writer or not.

Also as I understand it, `ex_ctrl` and `mem_ctrl` refer to instructions in their pipeline stages, ex, and mem, respectively — so `ex_ctrl.wxd` is set when the instruction in the ex stage is one that writes to a register (even though it won't do the write until the wb stage).

---

*Background*

*The rocket micro architecture suspends reading coprocessor results — as reading coprocessor results means writing a processor register, so also a write to the processor's register file — when `wxd` is asserted for instructions in the wb pipeline stage, giving processor instructions priority over coprocessor instructions.  A coprocessor result value is only transferred into the processor register file when `wxd` is set false (meaning the processor instruction won't write).*

*This mechanism limits the number of ports needed to write the register file.*